# Copy innerTEXT a href to clipboard by using a button

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am newer to JavaScript and am trying to figure out how to copy text from innerHTML to the clipboard, here is my code for the function that creates the innerHTML:

```
<script>
function updateQRCode() {
        qrcode.innerHTML = "";
        let req_auth_key = 'a12345-b12345-c12345';    
        let app_url = 'qrcodegenerator.com'                 
        let link = document.getElementById('linkval').value;
        let vcode = md5(link + req_auth_key);  // md5(T + K)
        let target = app_url + '?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + "&vcode=" + vcode;
        let newDiv = document.getElementById("linkdiv")
        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.innerText = target;
        newLink.href = target;
        newLink.setAttribute("id", "linkdiv")
        document.body.appendChild(newLink);
        newDiv.appendChild(newLink);
    }
</script>
```

The code above creates a clickable URL link that I can use to generate the QR code, however, I would like to create an option to copy that URL to the clipboard by using a simple button.  I know users could just right-click on the link to copy, but my project manager wants the button for ease of use.

I tried using the code below to copy the text, but I am unsure of some of the values since currently it copies "Copy" to the clipboard.

```
<div id="linkdiv">
    <button onclick="copyText()">Copy</button>
    <script>
        function copyText('a') {
            let copyLink = document.createElement("textarea");
            copyLink.value = event.target.innerHTML;
            document.body.appendChild(copyLink);
            copyLink.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(copyLink);
        }
    </script>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: *it copies "Copy"* - so, it's working fine.   `copyLink.value = event.target.innerHTML;` sets the text to be copied, which is the button you've just clicked's text , ie `"Copy"`

Comment: Yes - which is good, however, I am looking to copy the URL from the previous function.

Comment: `copyLink.value = variable_name_that_holds_text_to_be_copied`  (probably `= link` ?)

Comment: Only problem with that is the variable I need "target" from the previous function isn't global, so I don't know how to pull that into the copy function.  Can I nest this copy function into the previous function so that I can use that variable?  That also creates an issue with the button not being able to call the correct function, right?

Comment: `function updateQRCode() { ... return target; }`  `copyLink.value = updateQRCode()`

Comment: Would it be best practice to nest the copy function under updateQRCode()?

Comment: "nest *under*" - if you mean "*nest inside*" then no - just have the two functions at the same level.  Try to keep your scripts together (eg in a single `<script>` at the end of the html) rather than semi-random `<script>` tags in the middle of the html.